# How can we create a French speaking NativeChat bot?

Tags: telerik, progress-4gl, progress-db

According to the Progress website, NativeChat is supporting 72 languages including French. However, when we create a new bot, there is only 6 languages offered, and this doesn't include French (nor Spanish, Italian, Portuguese, etc).

Furthermore, there is warning inviting to choose carefully the bot language as it can't be change thereafter. I also looked at the documentation but there is nothing regarding this setting.

My question : 
How can we create a French speaking NativeChat bot?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the link to the right website directly into your question, please?  I found `https://www.progress.com/nativechat` but don't know if there is still a better page. Thanks!

Comment: Your can access the NativeChat service at : https://portal.nativechat.com/ 
From there, you can register to the development environment.

Comment: In all honesty this is a question that would be better suited for Progress' own technical support team. You may also find https://community.progress.com a better source of assistance.